# How to revert behavior of SeriesData to pre 12.1

Tags: series-expansion, undocumented, version-12.1

In Mathematica 12.0 and earlier,

```
SeriesData[x, 0, {1/u + Log[x/y]}, 0, 3, 1]
```

used to preserve its list of expressions in the form it was given.

[image]

Now, in Mathematica 12.1 and later, it seems to put things together *inside* the `SeriesData`.

[image]

I can't keep them apart without applying `Normal`.  This has seriously broken my code, and I need to revert to earlier behavior.  Is there an internal switch that fixes this behavior of `SeriesData`?

Comment: No internal switch for this. For what it's worth, your code was relying on undocumented behavior, and the more recent form of result is in no way "broken". Just saying.

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Do you know why the behavior was changed?  Is this form in some way better?

Comment: Probably it was a matter of making more use of `Together`. Offhand I do not recall the specific change but I can say that, in general, some internals work better when encountering series coefficients that are in that form.